# Phase of free neutron in a magnetic field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-spin

Let's consider two cases:

1. A neutron with a spin fixed along $\hat{z}$ moves along $x$ with constant momentum $\vec{p} = p_0 \hat{x}$ under the influence of a magnetic field $\vec{B} = B_0 \hat{z}$.
2. The same as above but with the spin flipped, i. e. spin fixed along $-\hat{z}$

**Question:** What's the phase difference between the two states for a given time?

**Attempt to answer:** There's a phase difference between them of $\propto e^{-i \omega t}$ where $\omega$ is the energy difference due to the Zeeman interaction.

Is this correct? I am rather insecure about conceptual things like these.